# How to remove a toe-touch drain stopper when the cap doesn't unscrew?

Tags: bathroom

Although many have asked about similar situations, none of the answers worked for me.
I am managing to twist the cap... but it's an "empty" twist; it doesn't come off. There is nowhere to stick a screwdriver under (which I tried anyway). How can I get it off?

Picture:

[image]

Comment: You can try pulling up while unscrewing. Sometimes the threads are corroded and the cap will just spin until a thread catches.

Comment: Image link is not working properly.